# Unity3d - Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Ray' to `Ray'

Tags: unity

I downloaded the free standard assets from the assets store, now I get alot of errors in my console.
e.g.

```
Assets/SampleScenes/Scripts/PlaceTargetWithMouse.cs(19,35): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.Ray' to `Ray'
```

This is the according script and I am not able to figure out why this happens, everything looks fine for me:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.SceneUtils
{
    public class PlaceTargetWithMouse : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float surfaceOffset = 1.5f;
        public GameObject setTargetOn;

        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {
            if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                return;
            }
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);    //<--- Error
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                return;
            }
            transform.position = hit.point + hit.normal*surfaceOffset;
            if (setTargetOn != null)
            {
                setTargetOn.SendMessage("SetTarget", transform);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you leave dislikes, then give a comment so I can improve myself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to solve it, I renamed `Ray` to `UnityEngine.Ray`.

```
UnityEngine.Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```